# Review Aggregate Google Rich Snippet - Error with review count

Tags: php, web-services, web-applications, web, seo

I have successfully implemented Google Rich Snippets on my web pages. But when I tried to use review aggregate Snippets, it gives me the below error: 
**"If count is specified in review aggregate, page should contain reviews. Otherwise you may want to use votes"**

I have got reviews on my page but why Google say something like this.

Comment: Read this article: http://www.seoskeptic.com/count-vs-votes-error-for-schema-org-aggregaterating/

Comment: Good article at SteelRat's link. You can get this "error" even if everything agrees as well. It's probably mostly an "info" bit rather than an "error.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the guidelines from Schema.org/AggregateRating and suffered the same error. 
If you haven't already, try changing itemprop to "ratingCount" instead of "reviewCount"
eg:

`div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"> <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="3.5"><meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="5">
</div>`

Comment: This is not a solution to the question, this simply changes "reviews" to "votes".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each review is marked up with the

```
<div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
```

schema

Comment: The error occurs despite this, whilst good advice it doesn't help solve the problem.