# Aggregate rating error on Local Business schema on microdata

Tags: microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

I have a plugin called RS Testimonials. This plugin will generate a schema for a localbusiness with aggregate rating and reviews. But the problem is the star ratng are not showing on rich snippet. I recently found that in Structured Data Testing Tool there is an error on my schema generated ny the RS testimonial plugins..

here is the sample code of my schema you can also test this in http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets.

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <p class="testimonial">
    </p>
    <div itemprop="reviews" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
        <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
            <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5">
            <img src="http://olathe.addictionrecoverycenterks.com/wp-content/plugins/RSTestimonials/i/images/olathe-rehab-star-5.png"
            border="0" align="absmiddle" style="decoration:none;">
        </div>
        <span itemprop="name">
            <strong>
                Finally successful!
            </strong>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span itemprop="description">
            Finally successful! This was not my first try at treatment, but it is
            the only one that worked. Addiction Recovery Center Olathe, KS has an excellent
            rehabilitation program, and if you work it you are going to get clean and
            sober!
        </span>
        <br>
        —
        <strong>
            <span itemprop="author">
                Clarckson
            </span>
        </strong>
        <em>
            , Olathe
        </em>
        <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2013-06-14">
        Jun 14, 2013
    </div>

    <span itemprop="name">
        Addiction Recovery Center Olathe KS
    </span>
    is rated
    <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <span itemprop="ratingValue">
            5
        </span>
        /5 based on
        <span itemprop="reviewCount">
            5
        </span>
        reviews.
    </span>
</div>
```

This is the error message I got in testing tool

**Error: If count is specified in review aggregate, page should contain reviews. Otherwise you may want to use votes. More information about aggregate reviews.**

Comment: Why don’t you include/quote the mentioned error in your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Review Aggregate Google Rich Snippet - Error with review count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135208/review-aggregate-google-rich-snippet-error-with-review-count)